# How to see how many instances where 2 dates generate more revenue combined than one?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a list of products that I want to see where a combination of two products out sold a single product using Pandas.

```
Date    Product   Price   

1/1/19   Laptop    $700
1/1/19   Laptop    $700
1/1/19   iPhone    $500
1/1/19   Beats     $250
1/1/19   iPhone    $500
1/2/19   iPhone    $500
1/2/19   Beats     $250
1/2/19   Laptop    $700
1/3/19   Beats     $150
1/3/19   Laptop    $700
1/3/19   iPhone    $500
1/3/19   Beats     $250
```

This is just sample data, but I would want to see what dates both Beats and iPhones get more combined revenue than laptops, and what specific dates, using Pandas. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the output of `df.to_dict()` so we can copy and paste it? (I'm assuming your dataframe is called `df` here)

Comment: could you show expected output?

Comment: The main expected output would be a value_counts() of instances where Beats and iPhone gross more and when laptops alone score more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```py
>>> df['ProductGroup'] = (df.Product == 'Laptop').replace({True : "Laptop", False : "Iphone & Beats" })
>>> df
         Date Product  Sale    ProductGroup
0  2019-01-01  Laptop   700          Laptop
1  2019-01-01  Laptop   700          Laptop
2  2019-01-01  iPhone   500  Iphone & Beats
3  2019-01-01   Beats   250  Iphone & Beats
4  2019-01-01  iPhone   500  Iphone & Beats
5  2019-01-02  iPhone   500  Iphone & Beats
6  2019-01-02   Beats   250  Iphone & Beats
7  2019-01-02  Laptop   700          Laptop
8  2019-01-03   Beats   150  Iphone & Beats
9  2019-01-03  Laptop   700          Laptop
10 2019-01-03  iPhone   500  Iphone & Beats
11 2019-01-03   Beats   250  Iphone & Beats
```

---

```
>>> df.groupby(['Date', 'ProductGroup']).sum().unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)
ProductGroup  Iphone & Beats  Laptop
Date
2019-01-01              1250    1400
2019-01-02               750     700
2019-01-03               900     700
```

---

```
>>> x[x['Iphone & Beats'] > x['Laptop']]
ProductGroup  Iphone & Beats  Laptop
Date
2019-01-02               750     700
2019-01-03               900     700
```

Answer (score 0):

First build a sum table:

```
df_sum = df.groupby(['Product', 'Date']).sum()
```

Which gets you:

```
                   Price
Product Date            
Beats   2019-01-01   250
        2019-01-02   250
        2019-01-03   400
Laptop  2019-01-01  1400
        2019-01-02   700
        2019-01-03   700
iPhone  2019-01-01  1000
        2019-01-02   500
        2019-01-03   500
```

Then do a comparison between the dates:

```
df_sum.loc[['Beats', 'iPhone']].groupby('Date').sum() > df_sum.loc['Laptop']
```

Results:

```
            Price
Date             
2019-01-01  False
2019-01-02   True
2019-01-03   True
```